# Assign value in integer returned from stored procedure + Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I am calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure. That stored procedure is returning an integer value always so I am accepting that value in one integer variable.

```
EXEC @IsBusinessDay  =  LiteIsWorkingDay @ExecutionStart
```

But even if stored procedure returning 1 value of the `@IsBusinessDay` is 0.

Code block

```
SELECT @ExecutionStart = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 107)

EXEC @IsBusinessDay  =  LiteIsWorkingDay @ExecutionStart

IF(@IsBusinessDay = 0)
BEGIN
    IF(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@InterMediateStartDate,108) >  CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),108))
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO TbJobQueue (JobId, ScheduleId, DueDate, Status, ExpiryDate, 
                                ProcessingDate, InputUser, InputTime, 
                                LastModifiedBy, LastModifiedTime)
        VALUES (@JobId, @ScheduleId,  @InterMediateStartDate,  'NQUE', NULL,
                NULL, 'Scheduler', GETDATE(), NULL, NULL)
    END
END
```

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some more information.
What's in your stored procedures, ...
Without more information, we can't help you

Comment: I am inserting records with one store procedure. Now to check whether today's day is business day or not i am assigning value of today's date to @ExecutionStart and call the procedure LiteIsWorkingDay.

Comment: This procedure will check in HolidayMaster that whether that day is working day or not. If working day then it returns 0 else it returns 1. so i am expecting value of 0 and 1 from that store procedure. That is giving proper result. even statement given above is giving proper result if called isolated. but when in Store proc value of IsBusinessDay remains 0 irrispactive of the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value of the stored procedure in a variable you have to make something like this:

1. Declare output parameter in the LiteIsWorkingDay stored procedure

   create procedure LiteIsWorkingDay 
   @ExecutionStart varchar(20), @IsBusinessDay int output
2. In LiteIsWorkingDay stored procedure you have to select a value for the @IsBusinessDay output parameter.
3. In the stored procedure that calls LiteIsWorkingDay you need to do something like this to get its value:

   declare @ExecutionStart varchar(20)
   select @ExecutionStart = convert(varchar, getdate(), 107)

   declare @IsBusinessDay int
   exec LiteIsWorkingDay, @IsBusinessDay output

And that's all. Now the variable @IsBusinessDay will have the value that you want :)